# Reading most recent blocks without syncing chain

Tags: transactions, synchronization, blocks

I would like to be able to read the newly created blocks and list of transactions it included within, without storing the chain on my desktop. Can that be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Infura. It's not decentralized, but that does not seem to be of interest to you.